# Confirm private AMI subscription agreement through EC2 API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

FreeBSD AMIs on AWS marketplace are private (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00KSS55FY/) and you need to agree to the subscription before you can create instances. I want to avoid this manual agreement confirmation to streamline the deployment of my application which should only need the EC2 API credentials to get up and running.

Is there an API call to EC2 (which I could do from jclouds or a regular REST client) that could confirm the agreement or is this strictly manual process? I can't find anything mentioned in the documentation or via quick google search.

Comment: I suspect that once you do it once, you should be able to create your own AMI from the instance you built from the marketplace AMI, and launch new instances from there. The system tracks when this is done, so you'll be charged the software fee for each clone you run, but since there is no software fee for this marketplace instance, there wouldn't be any actual cost.

Comment: Interesting idea, I might take a look at that.